# Designing the XML payload schema for a RESTful POST WCF service.....and arrays

Tags: wcf-rest

I wrote a simple test client a while back to test out my XML payload, but my service keeps giving me back 400 Bad Requests. The following is my DataContract, followed by an example payload:

```
[DataContract(Name = "TMGTLabel", Namespace = "http://Novartis.TMGT.TMGTLabelPrint")]
public class TMGTLabel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProposedfileName")]
    public string proposedfilename;

    [DataMember(Name = "LabelDataGroup")]
    public LabelData ldatagrp;
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://Novartis.TMGT.TMGTLabelPrint")]
public class LabelData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ldata")]
    public string[] ldata;
}

<TMGTLabel>
<ProposedfileName>TestLabelFileName</ProposedfileName>
  <LabelDataGroup>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 1</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 2</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 3</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 4</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 5</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 6</ldata></LabelData>
    <LabelData><ldata>sample 7</ldata></LabelData>
  </LabelDataGroup>
</TMGTLabel>
```

Is there anything wrong with my payload according to how I have my DataContract designed?